# knitr won't produce output for system commands

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

When running knit on a rmarkdown file the system commands, particularly wc and grep, are not producing any output. The lines I am trying to produce output for are below:

```
system("wc -l /foo/bar.csv")
system("grep -F .12345 /foo/bar.txt | wc -w")
```

Has anyone encountered this or does anyone know why this might be? These lines produce the expected output if given to the interpreter. All of my other code runs as expected.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `system2`? Or just doing the same operations in R?

Comment: Basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/36928322/559676

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `intern` parameter of `system` as in the following example where "date" is called.

```
result <- system('date', intern = TRUE)
print(result)
```

The result will be capturing the output in `result` into an R vector.

Comment: I liked your answer