# Capture.output not capturing all outputs in R

Tags: r

I am using `capture.output` function, but I think there are cases where it doesn't capture everything written to the process' stdout. Here are two examples:

```
capture.output(help(ls))
capture.output(system("wget --help"))
```

I am trying to understand why `capture.output` isn't capturing all stdout, in what situation I can expect it to not capture stdout, and am looking for a fix to make it capture all stdout.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36929590/2994949