# Why is RMarkdown not displaying code output?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using RStudio on Windows 10. Please help me get the output of the R System function to be included in my output document when I knit the markdown file. I have tried many combinations of chunk options that I found in the [official reference](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf).

In the Console, the output of:

```
system('java -version')
```

is:

java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)

However, when I put it into an RMardown document:

````
---
title: "Code Chunk Not Displaying Output"
output: html_document
---

```{r test}
system('java -version')
```
````

Unfortunately, instead of showing my java version, the formatted output for the chunk is:

```
## [1] 0
```

Comment: From [`?system`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html), *"intern: a logical (not NA) which indicates whether to capture the output of the command as an R character vector"*. Try `system("java -version", intern=TRUE)`. (What you're seeing is the exit code, where "0" typically means "no errors encountered".)

Comment: thanks r2 evans, tried intern=TRUE, still doesn't work

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928322/how-to-capture-the-output-of-system

Comment: Adding `intern=TRUE` is going to be the method for getting the output from `java -version` into your document. Can you please update your question to include the updated `system` call and a screenshot of the rendered HTML document? (If you cannot yet show images, that's okay, include it and we can edit your question to show the image.)

Comment: I specifically added "intern=TRUE" to the system function, knit the document again, and the output is the same. So I don't understand why I need to edit my question again to include intern=TRUE and a screenshot showing the same result?

Comment: Roman  my question is definitely related to the link you provided, thanks, and that link you provided is also linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388964/rmarkdown-not-outputting-results-of-system-command-to-html-file which is my exact question with no satisfactory answer.

Comment: and FYI as one of the related questions suggests, I tried cat(system('java -version', intern = TRUE), sep = '\n') , and that also does not work. At first I thought  I was doing something wrong with Rmarkdown, now I am wondering if there is something quirky about the system function.

Comment: Try `system2("java", "--version", stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE)`

Comment: r2evans that works! want to make an official answer out of it? Note it's supposed to be -version not --version

Comment: one more thing, the stdout parameter isn't required, this works: system2("java", "-version", stderr=TRUE)

Comment: yes, I included it just to check both angles at once ... with some utilities, it'll emit *something* on both. Answer forthcoming ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Up front, use:

```r
system2("java", "-version", stderr = TRUE)
```

(If you want to make sure that *any* command called, not just `java`, then (1) assume it accepts `-version`, and (2) also add `stdout = TRUE`. If there is no `stdout` to capture, then it does not harm.)

#### Why?

This is a (quick) discussion about *file descriptors* (fd). When a program runs, it may accept data (or something) on file descriptor 0, which is typically known as *standard input* or `stdin`. It can emit (send text/values/data) out on any number of file descriptors, but typically most programs use at least fd1 (*standard output*, `stdout`) and often but not always fd2 (*standard error*, `stderr`). The reason is so that command-line utilities can capture *intended output* on `stdout` and capture errors/warnings on `stderr`. In shell-speak:

```bash
#                         /-- this is redirecting stdout
#                         |            /-- this is redirecting stderr
#                         v            v
$ somecommand -arg1 -arg2 > output.log 2> error.log
```

Will send the intended (normal) output to the file `output.log`, and anything non-standard (or out-of-band or warnings or debugging or ...) to `error.log`. In many circumstances, an empty `error.log` is a good thing and "expected".

During my initial testing, since I don't have java, I was using `ls --version`, and `/bin/ls` sends its version information out on `stdout`. Apparently, `java` uses `stderr`.

(I finally verified with by switching to a command which should use `stderr`: the easiest way to reproduce without `java` around was:

````
---
title: "Code Chunk Not Displaying Output"
output: html_document
---

```{r test}
system("ls --versiommmmm", intern = TRUE)
```
````

which (1) did not have the expected `ls: unknown option -- versiommmmm` output, and (2) returned `## [1] 2` instead, indicating an exit status of 2. (Most utilities use an exit status of 0 to mean "all good", and anything else as an error. Some utilities go so far as the emit a specific exit status for specific errors, but it's generally safe to assume "not `0` means some error condition".)

In order to get R to do a system call and catch the stderr, I switched to `system2`, which allows one to capture `stderr=` (as well as `stdout=` separately).

Notes:

- `system2` takes the command to run as its first argument, and then all subsequent arguments as a character vector, so something like:

  ```r
  system2("java", c("Echo", "Drink Hot Java"))
  ```

  would call `java` with two arguments, `"Echo"` and the string. (Actually, that's not quite right ... see the next bullet.)
- both `system` and `system2` do really poor jobs of quoting things. If any of your arguments have embedded spaces, such as the call in the previous bullet, then the command will actually seem individual arguments. So the previous bullet's command actually calls `java` with *four* arguments, and is equivalent to `c("Echo", "Drink", "Hot", "Java")`. (I and many people consider this a significant problem with `system2`. The workarounds include using `shQuote` yourself or using the `processx` package, which does things *right*.)
- different arguments, where the equivalent of `system(..., intern=TRUE)` is `system2(..., stdout=TRUE)` ... and you gain the ability to use `stderr=`.